# How to add a plot legend to a Rotate Show expression

Tags: plotting, legending

I have a problem, the legend is shown in rotate form and I want it in normal form

```
Plotf = 
  Labeled[
    Rotate[Show[R5, e2, PlotRange -> All], 270 Degree ], 
    {"Depth m",  "Residual load kN"}, 
    {Left, Top}, 
    RotateLabel -> True]

Show[Plotf, 
  Epilog -> 
    Inset[
      Framed[
        Column[
          {PointLegend[{Blue}, {"   Measured"}], 
           LineLegend[{Red}, {"Estimated"}]}], 
        RoundingRadius -> 5], 
      Scaled[{0.8, 0.85}]]]
```

Comment: What is R5 and e2?

Comment: Just ListPlot point dear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but perhaps this example will give some idea on how to proceed.

Contrived data.

```
With[{n = 20},
 SeedRandom[42];
 p1 = ListLinePlot[RandomInteger[100, n], PlotStyle -> Red];
 p2 = ListPlot[RandomInteger[100, n], PlotStyle -> Blue];]
```

Plot

```
Legended[
  Labeled[
    Rotate[Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> All], 270 Degree], 
    {"Depth m", "Residual load kN"},
    {Left, Top},
    RotateLabel -> True],
  Column[
    {PointLegend[{Blue}, {"   Measured"}], 
     LineLegend[{Red}, {"Estimated"}]}]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you so much, it's really done  well

Comment: @MohammadSAl-tawaha. I'm glad you find my answer useful. Please consider accepting it. You can do that by clicking on the check mark that appears on the left of the answer below the down arrow.